# Como puedo hacer para que el evento de addClass(jquery) se ejecute 1 vez por columna de un table

Tags: jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#drawer").on("click",".picker",function(){
            $('.picker.color').removeClass('color')
            $(this).addClass('color');
        });

          function show(level_id,category_id){
            $('#drawer').html("");
            //TONOS
            if(level_id == '1' && category_id == '1'){

                createTable(5,2);
                $("#1-3").css({"background-color":"red"});

            }
            if(level_id == '2' && category_id == '1'){
                createTable(5,4);
                $("#1-3").css({"background-color":"red"});
                $("#3-3").css({"background-color":"red"});
            }

        }

        function createTable(row,cols){
        mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({id:"basicTable"});
        var rows = new Number(row);
        var cols = new Number (cols) + 1;
        var tr = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
            var content = "";
            for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {

                var clase = j == 1 || j == 3 ? "nopicker" : "picker";
                $('<td class="'+clase+'"></td>').attr({ id: [j]+"-"+ 
                 [i].join(' ')}).appendTo(row);
            }
         }

        mytable.appendTo("#drawer");
    }
```

}

html :

```
<div id="drawer"> </div>
```

puedo pintar por columna pero solo pinta 1 vez yo quiero que permita pintar 1 vez por cada columna que sea picker

Comment: ¿Ahora mismo ese código te funciona? Veo cosas que no me terminan de encajar. Además, creo que faltaría añadir más html, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function createTableTonos(row,cols){
        mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({id:"basicTable"});
        var rows = new Number(row);
        var cols = new Number (cols) + 1;
        var tr = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++){
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
            var content = "";
            for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {

                var clase = j == 1 || j == 3 ? "nopicker" : "picker";
                var content = "<td data-col='"+j+"' class='"+clase+" "+j+"' id='"+j+"-"+i+"'></td>";
                $(row).append(content);

            }
         }

        mytable.appendTo("#drawer");
    }
```

cambiandole el attr por lo que puse se arregla. gracias de todos modos.